# TimeoutException: InstaBot for comments

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I have this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from file import pw
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class InstaBot:
def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username=username
    self.password=password
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C://Program Files//webdrivers//chromedriver.exe')

def login(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    sleep(2)
    username_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")
    username_button.send_keys(self.username)
    password_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")
    password_button.send_keys(self.password)
    password_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(3)


def page(self,link):
    self.driver.get(link)
    sleep(3)


def comment(self):
    add_comment=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
    '//textarea[@aria-label="Add a comment..."]')))
    add_comment.send_keys('hello')



user=InstaBot('myusername' , pw)
user.login()
user.page('https://www.instagram.com/p/B_X4MvogIYljyucO445o8bo8ISdbIuNMRDx8vU0/')
user.comment()
```

And this element:

```
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" 
autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

And i take this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "botaki.py", line 43, in <module>
user.comment()
File "botaki.py", line 35, in comment
add_comment=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
'//textarea[@aria-label="Add a comment..."]')))
File "C:\Users\Κώστας Ρότσκας\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

At the beggining is fine, i log in and i go to my page in instagram but then i cant put text in comment.
I have tried everything like ActionsChains , or to replace element(aria-label) with placeholder or with class but nothing either. I dont know what to do now to my Instagram Bot 
So please help me guys!!!!!!!

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: to comment in instagram